# Django: dictionary to HTML table, when values are generators

Tags: python, html, django

I have a dictionary containing scraped Airbnb listings data:

```
all_data = {
                    'name' : self.detail('listing', 'name'),
                    'city' : self.detail('listing', 'city'),
                    'id' : self.detail('listing', 'id'),
                    'latitude' : self.detail('listing', 'lat'),
                    'longitude' : self.detail('listing', 'lng'),
                    'picture' : self.detail('listing', 'picture_url'),
                    'pictures' : self.detail('listing', 'picture_urls'),
                    'price' : self.detail('pricing_quote', 'rate', 'amount'),
                    'currency' : self.detail('pricing_quote', 'rate', 'currency')
                    }
```

That I am passing from Django view to template like this:

```
context = {'all_data':all_data}
return render(request, 'javascript/testjson.html', context)
```

The values in this dictionary are generators, yielding a specific listing detail.

How do I present this data in a HTML table form in the template?

So far I have the following for displaying the headers, but I don't know how to extract the data from generators into columns below those headers:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for key, value in all_data.items %}
            <th>{{key}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: {% for key, value in all_data.items %}

Comment: Thanks a lot, corrected now.

Comment: @ barciewicz you only written everything,just small mistake make men perfect

Answer (score 0):

you can update the html like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    {% for key in all_data.keys %}
        <th>{{key}}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  <tr>
    {% for value in all_data.values %}
        <td>
         {% for v in value %}
           {{v}}
         {% endfor %
       </td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
```

this will work....

Comment: Sadly it does not work, what happens is `<generator object AIRBNB_scraper_from_jason.detail at ...>` gets displayed once under each header.

Comment: again loop within the <td>

Comment: Thanks, but now it aligns the data under headers fine, but extracts it all in one row. And I want one row per listing.